# Proof that family of reciprocal exponential "wobbles" are everywhere differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, exponential-function, signal-processing, wavelets

The other day (for purpose of modelling temporary "wobbles") I investigated

$$f(t): t\to \exp\left(\frac{N\pi i}{N\pi|t|+1} \right), \forall t\in \mathbb R, N\in \mathbb N$$

I suppose it shall be trivial to prove it is differentiable everywhere infinitely many times except $t=0$. But how to show it for $t=0$? Or maybe it isn't differentiable there? If so, can we use some (algebraic or numerical) technique to get it differentiable there?

---

I suppose the closely related function:

$$g(t): t\to \exp\left(\frac{N\pi i}{N\pi t^2+1} \right), \forall t\in \mathbb R, N\in \mathbb N$$

[Is nicer in this regard](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20real%28%20exp%28i*%28pi*6%29%2F%28%28pi*6%29*t%5E2%2B1%29%29%20%29%20t%20%3D%20-2%20to%202)? As  far as I can tell all of it's derivatives shall follow $$g^{(k)}(t) = Q(t) \exp\left(\frac{N\pi i}{N\pi t^2+1} \right)$$

For some rational function $Q_k(t) = \frac{P_{k1}(t)}{P_{k2}(t)}$ for some sequence of polynomials $P_{k1},P_{k2}$.

Only remains to prove that $P_{k2}$ has no zeros on real line for any $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}.$$

Verify that this limit, which is the derivative of $f$ from the right at $0,$ exists and is a nonzero number $L.$ Now note that $f$ is even. Therefore the derivative of $f$ from the left is $-L\ne L.$ It follows that $f'(0)$ does not exist.

As for $g,$ it is the composition of $x\to e^{ix}$ with $t\to \dfrac{N\pi}{N\pi t^2+1}.$ Both of these functions are in $C^\infty(\mathbb R),$ hence so is $g.$ (No computations necessary.)

Comment: Aha. The $f$ is as I suspected, but the $g$ part was a bit new for me. Is it a short proof that chain rule inherits the most restrictive class of differentiability or how does it work?

Comment: $C^\infty$ composed with $C^\infty$ is $C^\infty$ comes from the chain rule.